# Lost in PendingIntent fields

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am a bit lost with PendingIntent.

As far as I could understand, it's a Token given to the OS to perform later (hence pending) operations.

I have an activity that launched a service. The service, occasionally creates a notification.
What I am trying to do, as the simplest of all, is to bring the activity to the front.

I am not sure where and how I create and to whom I send the PendingActivity.

- If I create it within the Activity, I need to send it to the service - HOW?
- If I create it within the service, how would the context be to call the activity? are these the same? - I though these are the same, as how the OS works, but it did not work for me.

Here are some code lines

This is not working btw StartService gets an Intent.
This code is in my activity

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NeglectedService.class);

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
            0,
            intent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    startService(contentIntent);
```

So, the correct one is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NeglectedService.class);
startService(contentIntent);
```

So I think to make the pending intent in my service, but this didn't work for me, as I am not sure how to reuse/use the intent

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, 
            extra, 
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
            0,
            intent, // not sure what intent to use here !!!!
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

    mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: Found the answer.
It seems that bit more trial and error.

What needed to be done, is use the Neglected.class in the intent. As it works, I still don't understand why and how.

I will play with the fields.


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Neglected.class);

Comment: Old habbits I guess ":-)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved
What needed to be done, is use the Neglected.class in the intent.